# search form error

Tags: sql, arrays, forms, search, select

I'm webdesigner and I touch NOTHING in development, so, I really need your help (exam in school). So, indeed, I've made a search form in the same page. There a field to search by town (ville) and the results should be appareate in a div. Sometimes it works, but I really need to fix that.

The error:  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\foodsurfing\index.php on line 55

There is the code

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/foodsurfing.php');
if(isset($_GET['recherche']))

$requete="SELECT * FROM fiche_membres WHERE ville LIKE '%".$_GET['recherche']."%'
LIMIT 0 , 1 ";
else
$requete="SELECT * FROM fiche_membres
LIMIT 1 , 1 ";

mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$resultat=mysql_query($requete);


if (false === $resultat) {
    echo mysql_error();
}


?>
```

and the result's div

```
<div id="gmap_result_container">    
   <div class="gmap_result">


<?php while($fiche_membres=mysql_fetch_array($resultat)) {?> <p>
<a class="prenom"><?php echo($fiche_membres['prenom']); ?></a>
<a> , </a>
<a class="ville"><?php echo($fiche_membres['ville']); ?></a></p>
<img src="images/avatar_unknown.jpg">
<p><?php echo($fiche_membres['experience_culinaire']); ?></p>
<p><a href="inscription.php" onMouseOver="roll.src='images/ensavoirplus_hover.png'" onMouseOut="roll.src='images/ensavoirplus.png'"><img src="images/ensavoirplus.png" name="roll" border="0" alt="En savoir plus" align="middle" class="ensavoirplus"></a></p>
<?php }?>
</div>      
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help !!
Glad to be into the community I just discover as beginner !

Comment: You echo the error, but you continue with the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning says that the *resource* is not valid which is parameter of `mysql_fetch_array()` method. You have to verify the reference before retrieving rows.

```
   if(isset($_GET['recherche']))
      $requete="SELECT * FROM fiche_membres WHERE ville 
              LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['recherche']) . "%' LIMIT 0 , 1 ";
   else
      $requete="SELECT * FROM fiche_membres LIMIT 1 , 1 ";

    $resultat=mysql_query($requete);
    if($resultat)
     {
       while($fiche_membres=mysql_fetch_array($resultat))
        {
         //
        }
      }
```